# postgresql unable to login

Tags: postgresql, authentication, role

I created a user named 'client', witch refuses to connect. 
Here's my client:

```
CREATE ROLE client LOGIN
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md5d5bc32b75da65fe60067f501a4bb6665'
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
GRANT viewers TO client;
```

Here's how I changed his password:

```
ALTER USER client PASSWORD 'client';
```

Here's how I fail to connect:

```
psql -h localhost -d core -U client
Password for user client: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "client"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "client"
```

What have I done wrong? (I did tried restarting)

Just in case there are some more dumps:

viewers group:

```
CREATE ROLE viewers LOGIN
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
```

core database

```
CREATE DATABASE core
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE core TO public;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE core TO postgres;
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE core TO viewers;
```

Comment: recommended way for changing password is #\password user

Comment: I just did, it did not help, result is the same

Comment: I am curious if it's refusing to let you log in because of your `VALID UNTIL` clause.. I have not used it, personally - so it's only a suspicion.

Comment: I did not set It, it was set by default. I got this user dump from pgadmin

Comment: Could it be something with group viewers? @JoishiBodio

Comment: Not that I know of .. granting `viewers` to `client` should not affect client's ability to log in at all.. But I'm not a master of PostgreSQL ..

Comment: I posted some more dumps @JoishiBodio

Comment: When I look at my local install Postgres and the roles there-in on my local machine using PgAdminIII (as you say you have) .. I DO NOT have a `VALID UNTIL` clause as part of my roles. I also created them manually (as opposed to using some PgAdmin script). I'm still suspicious that is the issue.

Comment: Tried to remove it, and it worked! thank you. I'm still confused about how it got there... Would you post your answer @JoishiBodio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue `ALTER ROLE client VALID UNTIL 'infinity'` and it will remove the VALID UNTIL clause.